# Query firebase data with dynamically current timestampt

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I have a data something like this:

```
+ item1
    |---- date : 1512008295000
    |---- etc : etc
```

I use this query to get data start at current timestamp

```
Query query = Utils.getFirebaseDb().getReference()
        .child("registration")
        .child(mUser.getUid())
        .orderByChild("date")
        .startAt(DateTime.now().getMillis());
```

however, the `DateTime.now().getMillis()` is always changing,

suppose I query this on `1512008080000` which is, November 30, 2017 2:14:40, I will got the item with `date : 1512008295000` which is November 30, 2017 2:18:15, then 5 minute later, I still got item with `date : 1512008295000`, even current timestamp is `1512008380000` or November 30, 2017 2:19:40.

How i can query with dynamically changing current timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not answer to your question, but I think it's a workarround to your problem.

First, add new node that identity the item date is passed, something like this

```
+ item1
    |---- date : 1512008295000
    |---- passed : false
    |---- etc : etc
```

then change your query to this:

```
Query query = Utils.getFirebaseDb().getReference()
        .child("pendaftaran")
        .child(mUser.getUid())
        .orderByChild("passed")
        .equalTo(false);
```

Then on your `onBindViewHolder` check if the date is passed, and then change `passed` value to true if it already passed:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(YourHolder holder, int position, Model model) {

    boolean passed = model.getDate() < DateTime.now().getMillis();
    if (passed) {
       getRef(position).child("passed").setValue(true);
    } 
}
```

or if you do not need the passed item anymore, just delete it

```
getRef(position).removeValue();
```

whit this, you do not need to create additional node, and you still can order the query using date.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass a dynamic timestamp into a Firebase Database query. If you want to drop the items dynamically can *either* change the query regularly *and/or* remove the outdated items from the display locally.